# SELECT文で用いられるLIKEや _ % の意味は？

Tags: sql

WHEREの後の条件に使われる式として、以下の記載があるのですが、
具体例として、SELECT文があっての説明が無いので、式の意味、SELECT文に、どのような形で出てきて、どのように解釈したらいいのかわかりません。

> LIKE"_野菜%" 
>   (意味) "野菜"を含む文字列。_は一文字、%は任意文字数のワイルドカード

どういうことでしょうか？

Comment: 結局のところ、この質問はLIKEの用法が分からなかったのか、ワイルドカードが分からなかったのかどちらだったのでしょう？それとも両方？

Answer (score 3):

likeは文字列をパターン検索する時に使うもので、`カラム名 like 'パターン文字'`の様に使います。

`_`は任意の一文字、`%`は「0文字以上」の任意の文字列なので'like '_野菜%'は「野菜」の前に一文字、「野菜」の後は文字列があってもなくてもいいものを検索します。

```
create table test1 (
  comment varchar(255)
);
insert into test1 values ('野菜大好き');
insert into test1 values ('温野菜大好き');
insert into test1 values ('温野菜');
insert into test1 values ('無農薬野菜大好き');

select * from test1 where comment like '_野菜%';
```

実行結果

```
温野菜大好き
温野菜
```

- 「野菜大好き」は「野菜」の前に文字がないのでselectされません。
- 「無農薬野菜大好き」は「野菜」の前が3文字なのでselectされません。

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/184e0/1

Comment: tag1216 様  御回答ありがとうございます。理解出来ました。

Comment: このサイトでは回答にコメントでお礼を書くことは必須ではありません。代わりに投票と承認という機能があります。[自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) [「ありがとう」というコメントは禁止？](http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1693/%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%8C%E3%81%A8%E3%81%86-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%82%B3%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%81%AF%E7%A6%81%E6%AD%A2)

Answer (score 0):

_ および % はワイルドカードです。

_ は任意の一文字を表すので、`LIKE "_野菜"` は「お野菜」「生野菜」などが、
% は0文字以上の任意の文字列を表し、`LIKE "野菜%"` は「野菜」「野菜ジュース」などが該当します。

https://technet.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: T.Sa 様  御回答ありがとうございます。理解出来ました。

Answer (score 0):

使用例があればいいのかな？

```
SELECT * FROM tblName WHERE fieldName LIKE '_野菜%'

SELECT 【表示したいフィールド】 
FROM 【テーブル名】 
WHERE 【検索対象のフィールド】LIKE '【検索パターン】'
```

【検索パターン】にはワイルドカードが使用できます。
ワイルドカードの説明は他の方がされているので、詳しくはそちらを参照してください。

Comment: Myaku 様  御回答ありがとうございます。理解出来ました。